# addsubview after another subview

Tags: iphone, uiview, sdk, addsubview

I know its mad but here it goes:

i load a splashView to my app: on viewDidLoad:

```
[self.view addSubview:splashView];    

UIViewAnimationOptions options = UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:3.0 options:options animations:^{            
    splashView.alpha = 0.0f;
    splashView.frame = CGRectMake(512,384,-10,-10);
}

completion:^(BOOL finished){                          
    [splashView removeFromSuperview]; 
}];
```

Nothing special to the code here.

however, when i try to load the same view as an action through a button
NOTHING happens:

```
-(IBAction)showSplash:(id)sender {
    [self.view addSubview:splashView];

    UIViewAnimationOptions options = UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:3.0 options:options animations:^{
        splashView.alpha = 0.0f;
        splashView.frame = CGRectMake(512,384,-10,-10);
    }

    completion:^(BOOL finished){ 
        [splashView removeFromSuperview]; 
    }];
}
```

why is this happening?

By the way if i DO NOT load the splashView on the viewDidLoad and then use the button (action) it works ok!

is this normal behavior?

Comment: How you are calling this action, is it through xib or you have written some code, if their is some code for that then post that also. Otherwise it should work in both the cases.

Comment: what you see is what you get in terms of coding...(nothing fancy about it, simple stuff) :) Only one viewcontroller one xib (with two UIviews in it). all connections are ok.

Comment: Also it seems like view memory issue, when u remove a view from a superview will call superview's release, so not if you are calling that second time then you need to retain that as well.

Comment: that is not correct! i do not need to retain it at all! in fact it must be released and this is how apple recommends things to be done. Thank you for your response though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reset the alpha value before fading the splash view out.

```
splashView.alpha = 1.0f;
```

Comment: it cant be that simple!!!! lol YOU ARE A STAR!!!! i cant believe im so stupid NOT to see that!